# Need to encode audio byte[] as string to be transferred via JSON. Will be encoded and sent from C# and read as audio bytes in Java

Tags: java, c#, json, audio, encode

So I have found many similar questions and what it seems to come down to is difference in opinion on what encoding format you use. I have tried both Base64 and UTF-8. When I used Base64, the bytes seems to completely change on the Java side when I decode them and the sound is basically just static noise. When I use UTF-8, however, I can still hear the original sound in there, but it is very distorted and noisy, almost inaudible, but definitely still in there. I think this is because UTF-8 doesn't have characters for many of the audio bytes so many of them are lost in the process of encoding and decoding, which is why I tried base64, but that results in much worse audio. I am streaming live mic audio, so I do not have an audio file I can compare bytes to for the encoding types after it gets to Java.

The whole idea is I want to package up the audio bytes inside a JSON string to send from C# to Java instead of streaming the raw audio bytes alone (which works perfectly fine). Thea reason I want to do it this way is because I want to be able to communicate other non-audio things as well and was planning on using JSON for that too.

Is there a better way to encode the audio as a string which I can use in JSON? Or are audio bytes basically going to result in lost data no matter what if you try to encode them as a string?

For my base64 attempt, in C# I use:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(byteBuffer);
```

And on the Java side I tried decode with

```
DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(audioBufferData);
```

and

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();                            
byte[] bufferBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(audioBufferData);
```

For UTF-8, in C# I used

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBuffer);
```

and in Java

```
audioBufferData.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I am using an asset called "NatMic" in Unity to get live mic input. It gives me a float[] sampleBuffer which is converted to bytes as follows:

```
    var shortBuffer = new short[sampleBuffer.Length];
    var byteBuffer = new byte[Buffer.ByteLength(shortBuffer)];
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleBuffer.Length; i++)
        shortBuffer[i] = (short)(sampleBuffer[i] * short.MaxValue);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(shortBuffer, 0, byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
```

And then byteBuffer is encoded as above and sent along to the server. If I send the bytes without encoding and play them back directly with a Little Endian format SourceDataLine in Java, it sounds perfect, but after encoding to base64, I must change the SourceDataLine's format to expect Big Endian for it to playback correctly. For other reasons, I must maintain a Little Endian order.

Comment: Send known data in base64, decode, see what’s wrong. Are you sure the playback is set to proper signedness and endianness? Base64 will not alter the data in any way.

Comment: Could you post your attempts? Or at the very least, post the raw byte version.

Comment: Hey guys, I added some more code. 

Yes, the audio data is formatted properly. If I don't encode as a string and simply send the audio over as bytes, I can play it back in Java and it sounds absolutely perfect. Something is happening with encoding and decoding that causes it to become static. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Then you’ll need to check endianness, for example. That’s the most logical problem

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , Yep, you were right. I'll select it as the answer if you post your comment as the answer. After decoding it was BigEndian but before I had it set up to expect LittleEndian.

Comment: Is there a way to encode to Base64 but maintain Little Endian byte order? I can see that using other encoding formats, Little Endian or Big Endian can be specified when encoding and decoding, but all of those formats result in data loss or other problems that base64 does not suffer from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 will encode the bytes you give it directly and will not cause problems. Most likely the issue is endianness, which is different on each end. The conversion from and to bytes needs to be the same on both ends. You haven’t shown how you get the byte buffer from the 16bit audio data so can’t suggest any corrections to that part.

By default Java is big endian whereas .NET goes by whatever the underlying architecture is, usually little endian, so there needs to be a swap at some point. Java’s `ByteBuffer` does support setting endianness so that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was indeed what was wrong. I added some more details to the original question that may help determine why encoding appears to be changing the ordering to Big Endian.

Comment: I'm surprised to read that Java audio is by default big endian. I've only come across and worked with it as little-endian. Where is this default mentioned or specified?